# Query para somar campos de duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Necessito de uma query onde vou precisar somar as pessoas por cor e raça, distintamente, por exemplo, fazer a somatória não somente por nome, mas também por cor e raça iguais. Eu tentei algo abaixo, mas está somando somente os nomes iguais.

```
select COUNT(*), pessoas.nome, qualidades.cor, qualidades.raça                                  
from pessoas, qualidades where pessoas.id_qualidades_pess=qualidades.id_qualidades
group by pessoas.nome
```

Obrigado,

Comment: Adicione os campos `cor` e `raça` ao `GROUP BY` e tem a sua solução!

Comment: Deu certo!!!! obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta deixar somente o requerido no "group"

```
select COUNT(*), qualidades.cor, qualidades.raça                                  
from pessoas, qualidades 
where pessoas.id_qualidades_pess=qualidades.id_qualidades
group by qualidades.cor, qualidades.raça

 [Documentação][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrupando pelos campos que são importantes para você, conforme a query abaixo onde foi adicionado os campo raça e cor no agrupamento,

```
  select 
        COUNT(*), 
        pessoas.nome,
        qualidades.cor, 
        qualidades.raça                                  
    from pessoas, qualidades 
    where pessoas.id_qualidades_pess=qualidades.id_qualidades
    group by pessoas.nome
        qualidades.cor, 
        qualidades.raça
```